# C Programming - reading space separated strings into BST

Tags: c, scanf, binary-search-tree

Im trying to read user input of peoples names, first and last separated by spaces and individual names separated by newlines.

for example:

George Bush

Barack Obama

Donald Trump

This is my code thus far:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  char string[20+1];
  struct bst* tree = NULL;
  printf("Enter some strings: \n");

  while (scanf("%[^\n]%*c",string)) {
     tree=insert(tree,string);
  } 
}
```

My insert function is:

```
struct bst*
insert(struct bst* tree, char input[]) {
    struct bst* newnode;
    newnode = (struct bst*)malloc(sizeof(*newnode));

    strcpy(newnode->data, input);
    newnode->left = newnode->right = NULL;

    if (tree == NULL) {
        return newnode;
    } 

    if (strcmp(input,tree->data)<0) {
        tree->left=insert(tree->left,input);
    } else {
        tree->right=insert(tree->right,input);
    }
    return tree;
  }
```

The problem is that there's no end to the scanning of user input. 
When i change the scanf to scanf("%s",string) it works however i cannot store first and last name because theyre separated by spaces.

Comment: `while (scanf("%[^\n]%*c",string))` should be `while (scanf("%[^\n]%*c",string) == 1)` because `scanf` will return a non-zero value when it reaches the end-of-file, and that will result in an infinite loop.

Comment: Once that's fixed, you can just check the length of the string with `strlen` and `break` the loop when the length is 0.

Comment: thankyou for the tip about strlen and breaking when the length is 0!

Comment: @user3386109 Looks like you can make a decent answer for this.

Answer (score 0):

Reference to what was pointed out in the comments,

The return value of `scanf` from [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf):

> Number of receiving arguments successfully assigned (which may be zero in case a matching failure occurred before the first receiving argument was assigned), **or EOF if input failure occurs before the first receiving argument was assigned**.

The condition in `while` needs to be changed because:

> [EOF](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io) is a integer constant expression of type `int` and **negative value**.

So change the `while` to:

```
while (scanf("%[^\n]%*c",string) == 1)
```